# Is it possible to unzip in parallel with AES-256 encryption?

Tags: linux, encryption, zip, unzip, 7za

I compressed and encrypted (AES256) a folder with millions of JSONs using (in Ubuntu):

```
7za a -tzip -p -mem=AES256 json.zip json/
```

The compression seems to have gone fast, 4 hours or so. Now, I am decompressing/unencrypting the json.zip:

```
7za x json.zip
```

But it will take around a week. I noticed that it is using only one CPU

Is there a tool to decompress/unencrypted the files in parallel?

---

#### EDIT: Zip/Encryption uses all CPUs, but not unzip/decryption

I just tested both processes while observing the CPU usage.

- `7za a -tzip -p -mem=AES256 json.zip json/` uses all CPUs
- `7za x json.zip json/` uses only one

I tested this on the same machine to make sure it is not a configuration issue.

---

## EDIT: Environment description

I need to transfer via network (`ssh`) 8M files compressed and encrypted with AES 256 from machine A to machine B. Here are the steps:

1. The files on machine A live in a an encrypted (LUKS) SSD disk in a folder called json. I managed to compress them in ~4 hours with  `7za a -tzip -p -mem=AES256 json.zip json/`
2. I transferred the json.zip to machine B via ssh
3. I am un-compressing the files in machine B in a non-encrypted SSD disk with `7za x json.zip`. It will take 7 days. I tested the disk and it works properly.

I am also considering to forget about the compression. I only need to transfer the files encrypted, compression just makes sense to keep smaller backups (which I will need). This will be a recurrent task at some point, so it will certainly become a problem.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131388/discussion-on-question-by-toto-tico-is-it-possible-to-unzip-in-parallel-with-aes).